# How to show Font Awesome icons on Rails select_tag

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown in my `form_tag` similar to the one below for my `@icons = Icon.all` model:

```
<%= select_tag :icon_id, options_for_select(@icons.collect{ |u| [u.icon_code, u.id] }), class: "form-control" %>
```

This is a dropdown for font awesome icons but i am unable to render them on the browser. Is it possible to do so without installing a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently so:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/996

"However, FontAwesome is a unicode font based iconset, and so it is possible to include an icon in an option, or a select list, simply by referencing it's unicode character directly."

[image]

I'd just check your output and amend you option and style tags accordingly

Comment: html selects shows only texts. However aren't Font Awesome icons a font-based icon set. I was just thinking if somehow i can use the unicode directly and render it.

Comment: FontAwesome icons - like most of the other "icon" sets prepend a `:before` pseudoclass to your element. That pseudoclass has the appropriate font loaded, with the `content` attribute populated with the unicode to call the character. Thus you'll have to include some element with a "class" that has the font-awesome font in order for it to work